# Retrieving PDF file with cURL and an invoice generator API

Tags: php, curl

For my last university project of this semester, I am trying to generate an invoice with an API found on the web, calling it with cURL which I think it's the most simple option.

Unfortunately, when I execute the code I do not receive a readable page or a pdf file and I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
      <?php



    $invoice = array(
        "logo" => "test.dev", // url to logo
        "from" => "Wouter van Marrum \n<a href=\"http://www.concept-core.nl\">concept-core.nl</a>", // The name of your organization
        "to" => "marleen", // The entity being billed - multiple lines ok
        "number" => 20001, // Invoice number
        //"purchase_order" => "", // Purchase order number
        "date" => null, // Invoice date
        "due_date" => null, // Invoice due date
        "payment_terms" => null, // Payment terms summary (i.e. NET 30)
        // items
        "items[0][name]" => "Website",
        "items[0][quantity]" => 1,
        "items[0][unit_cost]" => 300,
        "items[1][name]" => "logo",
        "items[1][quantity]" => 1,
        "items[1][unit_cost]" => 150,
        // End items
        // Fields
        "fields[tax]" => true, // can be true, false
        "fields[discounts]" => false, // Subtotal discounts - numbers only
        "fields[shipping]" => false, // Can be true or false
        // End fields
        "tax"=> 21, // Tax - numbers only
        "amount_paid" => 0, // Amount paid - numbers only
        "notes" => "", // Notes - any extra information not included elsewhere
        "terms" => "Lees dit", // Terms and conditions - all the details
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://invoice-generator.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $invoice);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);

  $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://invoice-generator.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $invoice);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invoice_'.$date->toDateString().'.pdf"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($result));




    curl_close($ch);



    echo $result;
```

I have found the documentation for this API here (https://github.com/wotta/Invoiced-backup/blob/master/app/ConceptCore/Invoiced/Core.php) but I can't understand which additional steps I am missing.

Just to give you an idea, this is part of what I see when executing the code:

%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (��Invoice) /Creator (��wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1) /Producer (��Qt 4.8.6) /CreationDate (D:20191206214540Z) >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /SA true /SM 0.02 /ca 1.0 /CA 1.0 /AIS false /SMask /None>> endobj 4 0 obj [/Pattern /DeviceRGB] endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >> endobj 5 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Contents 9 0 R /Resources 11 0 R /Annots 12 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] >> endobj 11 0 obj << /ColorSpace << /PCSp 4 0 R /CSp /DeviceRGB /CSpg /DeviceGray >> /ExtGState << /GSa 3 0 R >> /Pattern << >> /Font << /F6 6 0 R /F7 7 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 12 0 obj [ ] endobj 9 0 obj << /Length 10 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream x��\Ko�6��W�@�@Q Σ@��a�C�mZ,�E�=��"i���Ɏ7�Rn�Ҍ�y}C):�?=�N��J.��&��y��1�K?���( \Q�n���:/���y�����|鸉��Gx`+&u�u���L t��p�K����s��L>�>>�>��;o��AW�vS�r���A�l�������K���.������(�26�BX��w^�Kf��PD2� �ϝ6R�W�7]�h)Ӂ^�S҅u�Kk��]h;a2P����j*ױ?E�]Ig�g���K�˱��B�������';*ň����U��?tO!^�(P��@�}75<����U ��9+LE�ʊ�.E�*��uW�Glj��R��R�����)a:m�&���U��J�|��b��ӳ~��]�"-y|"Ʉ���d�P�<~"?��H?w����L����x�G>�4:�Ҝ[{��;�����ks̹�_��yìS2��Kwh�7��K�rq�A� ��GA�t^s��C ���l�+���Jkj�a,nz�~��{)����)I)��R/�~#u]�3�7�fi�NWt���-%V�A��wA��T���R��i�O�ZN����԰q�B���eRY[+{��4�Oqx����B�YeM��c���@�\eF^��� P����43m���q�M^�L�ѐc�ye0e�Dd9�L[]L�WA<��=&�AE��׵�F�a�o���\�9��NڛJ}1 �'-GUp �2x)�1S��6�ݤ���dѦό3���7}��;���h���o����?�eK�K�W ��3����;ć^C4ZU�Ait�ee������zM;Q)

Comment: That looks like a PDF to me. Try adding the appropriate Content-Type header for a PDF: `header('Content-type: application/pdf');`

Comment: That looks like the correct beginning of a PDF. What happens if you save it to a file with a file extension of PDF? Are you able to open it? Or emit the proper headers to indicate that it is a PDF and echo the results.

Comment: I have tried to add the Content-type and still get the same result. 
I am "testing" the code on the browser to see if I am able to retrieve the invoice. $echo would be the best option but atm is not really working :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need add `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` to specify that CURL return the result as a string and not be formatted.
In this case, with this code, the result will be a readable PDF file:
[screenshot of resultant pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UQ4c.png)

In addition, **in this case** you must replace `header('Content-Length: ' . $response->getHeader('Content-Length')[0]);` to `header('Content-Length: '.strlen($result));`
And because of the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` flag, you will not use `$file = $result-> getBody();`, try deleting it.

I attached a link with the modified code, currently working on my server: https://pastebin.com/JDgKjUt8

I recommend that you enable error logging to verify what went wrong: [Showing all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I have tried and now it went from an incomprehensible page to a completely grey page, which at least now looks more like a pdf XD
Unfortunately, there is still something which is not working

Comment: Please, read again the response that has been modified for you case.

Comment: Oh wow, you made it work! I'm editing the first question with the code that I am testing, which somehow I can't make work, could you post your running code, please :-)

Comment: Added pastebin link ;)

Comment: thank you very very much Giuliano!! davvero grazie :-)